# "Born to be chained" Kata 99% solution

Tags: javascript

I have a function to solve kata on Code Wars which is named ["Born to be chained"](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54c27ef1fb7da0118600046a/train/javascript), and everything looks good, every test was passed, except the last one. "addOneArray"

I looked at the code of others, and it was identical to mine. Question is: What's wrong with my code?

The only distinguishing feature is that a new instance is created there every time, but I have almost the same thing.
Code that passed all tests:

```
function chain(fns) {
        let Chain = function (val) {
          this.execute = () => val
        }
        for (let i in fns)
          Chain.prototype[i] = function (a, b) {
            let val = this.execute(),
              args = val === null ? [a, b] : [val, a]
            return new Chain(fns[i](...args))
          }
        return new Chain(null)
      }
```

My code:

```
let chain = function (fns) {
  let metds = {
    execute() {
      return this.res
    }
  }

  for (let key in fns) {
    metds[key] = (...args) => {
      metds.res = !metds.res ? fns[key](...args) : fns[key](metds.res, ...args)
      return {
        ...metds
      }
    }
  }

  return metds
}
```

Comment: "*Note that the chain can be reused (the internal state is not stored)*" - your code does mutate the `metds.res`. It should only put the new result in the new object that you already create with the spread syntax in the literal.

Comment: I thought that transferring a new object was enough, because it works fine with simple numbers. I solve this with your advice. Thank you!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Decision:

```
for (let key in fns) {
  metds[key] = function (...args) {
    let res = !this.res ? fns[key](...args) : fns[key](this.res, ...args)
    return {
      ...metds,
      res
    }
  }
}
```